# In-app Billiing

Tags: android

I want to Integrate In-app billing functionality with my application. I have read the topic "Implementing In-app Billing" on  android developer site.
There is a point "1.Log in to your Google Play publisher account."
Is there a trial publisher account (free) facility on Google Play,if yes what is the procedure to create that account?

Comment: Nope, there's no free developer account on Google Play. You need to pay for it.

Comment: Try http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/integrate-in-app-billing-just-3-lines-of-code-in-your-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can test in-app billing with your android developer account.

due to android developer site

The Google Play publisher site provides several tools that help you test your in-app billing implementation before it is published. You can use these tools to create test accounts and purchase special reserved items that send static billing responses to your application.

To test in-app billing in an application you must install the application on an Android-powered device. You cannot use the Android emulator to test in-app billing. The device you use for testing must run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or later platform (API level 4 or higher), and have the most current version of the Google Play application installed. If a device is not running the most current Google Play application, your application won't be able to send in-app billing requests to Google Play. For general information about how to set up a device for use in developing Android applications, see Using Hardware Devices.

please read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) for further details